# Getting error in RadioGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a `Radio Group` dynamically, but I am getting an error saying "The child already has a parent call removeView() on parent first". Below is my code:

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getContext());
        RadioButton[] allSongsRadio = new RadioButton[countOfAllSongs];

        ArrayList<String> allSongsInMap = new ArrayList<>(countOfAllSongs);
        for(final String eachMood : allSongs.keySet()) {
            for(String eachSong : allSongs.get(eachMood)) {
                allSongsInMap.add(eachMood+" : "+eachSong);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<allSongsInMap.size();i++){
            final String eachSong = allSongsInMap.get(i);
            LinearLayout playButtonAndSeekBar = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            final FloatingActionButton playButton = new FloatingActionButton(getContext());
            playButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE));
            playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            playButton.setSize(FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
            playButton.setId(++playButtonId);
            SeekBar seekBarForEachSong = new SeekBar(getContext());
            layoutDetails = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layoutDetails.rightMargin = 50;
            seekBarForEachSong.setLayoutParams(layoutDetails);
            allSongsRadio[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(playButton);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(seekBarForEachSong);

            eachSongPanel.addView(playButtonAndSeekBar);
            rg.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
            dialogContainer.addView(eachSongPanel);
        }
        dialogContainer.addView(rg);

    }
```

Need help guys.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and indicate which line in your code causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error cause you are adding the same component to two different `ViewGroup` which is not allowed in `Android` (each element belong to one ViewGroup Parent), there is where you are doing so:

First you are adding the radio button here :

```
playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
```

And then you are adding it to the radio group :

```
rg.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
```

At this point `allSongsRadio[i]` belong to `playButtonAndSeekBar` you cannot add it to another ViewGroup.

To correct you code, add the buttons to just the radio group, then finally add the whole radio group to `playButtonAndSeekBar` regarding to your desired design.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Changed like this:   seekBarForEachSong.setLayoutParams(layoutDetails);
            allSongsRadio[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());
            rg.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(playButton);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(seekBarForEachSong);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(rg);

            eachSongPanel.addView(playButtonAndSeekBar);
            dialogContainer.addView(eachSongPanel);
            }
//            dialogContainer.addView(rg);

Comment: you've generated another error, look here : `playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(rg);` you are adding `rg` in the loop to a new LinearLayout every iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. :) .I think i understood whats wrong i was doing. These are the changes that i made, but now though i can see the buttons, still i can select multiple buttons.

Comment: seekBarForEachSong.setLayoutParams(layoutDetails);
            allSongsRadio[i] = new RadioButton(getContext());
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(allSongsRadio[i]);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(playButton);
            playButtonAndSeekBar.addView(seekBarForEachSong);
            eachSongPanel.addView(playButtonAndSeekBar);
            rg.addView(eachSongPanel);
            }
            dialogContainer.addView(rg);

Comment: yes cause radio buttons need to be direct childs of radio group but in your case the radio buttons are not directly added top the radio group, instead you are adding them to another layout (`playButtonAndSeekBar`) then to anther one  (`eachSongPanel`) then to the radio group. for a work around i suggest using `playButtonAndSeekBar` as RadioGroup since RadioGroup inherit Linear layout

Comment: Fantastic man. Thanks a ton. Got the point. And a very happy new year in advance to you. Cheers :)

Comment: Do you know about replacing fragments in a tabbed activity? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384357/how-can-i-create-fragments-for-my-three-tabs-tabbed-layout-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment69980245_41384357

Comment: glad it helps, for the other question i didn't use Fragments too much but i'll take a look.